# How can I perform an action the first time a new client connects to my server?

Tags: java, spring, tcp, spring-integration

I have a Spring-Integrations server setup that will accept tcp connection through a `DirectChannel` And then perform some math on the message and send an new message out to another server with another `DirectChannel` and it works great. Now I need to have an action take place the first time a connection is established between the server and a new client. I have been looking all week and can't find the right way to do this. All of my Integration configuration is Java (no xml). Can I get some help figuring out how to capture or listen for the first time a new client connection with my server?
Thanks for help in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AbstractServerConnectionFactory` implementations publish `TcpConnectionOpenEvent` in that case. That is regular Spring Application Event, although you can handle it with the `ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer`.

See more info in the Reference Manual: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.5.RELEASE/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-events

Comment: This worked so well I cannot thank you enough. For newer people like me my solution was to add a bean `ApplicationListener<TcpConnectionOpenEvent>` and from there I can get the event information that I needed